# “X” letter meaning next to VHF frequency in jeppessen plates

Tags: radio-communications

DOH airport implemented new VHF frequencies in their new SID/STAR/APP jeppessen charts.
What does the « X »letter means next to these frequencies
[image]

Answer (score 11):

This information is from the [INTRODUCTION TO
JEPPESEN NAVIGATION CHARTS](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf) Guide, page 48.

[image]

The letter `X` means "Communication Frequency On Request."

Comment: This begs the question (for us non-pilots) of what does "Communication Frequency on Request" mean.... :)

Comment: @FreeMan Typically on SID/STARS/ Instrument Approaches there are frequencies published on the charts that provide the pilots with what frequency they can expect to use during the various segments of flight.  When there is an "X" suffix on a frequency it means that this frequency will be used only if requested by ATC.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you sir!